# function that validates an address in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I made 3 functions which work perfectly fine each alone:

checkNumber -checks if a string contains only digits

checkStreetName - checks if a string contains only letters

isAbbreviation - checks if a string is "Ave." or "St."

I made the function checkAdd that uses the other functions

the function checkAdd gets a list of strings and should return True if:

the first string contains only numbers

the last string ="Ave." or St."

and the rest of the strings in between should contain letters

for example: ["123", "asdd", "Ave."] is legal address

However I am getting false instead of true and I don't know why. I checked each and every function alone. (by the way I am not aloud to use some of the ready made functions in Haskell)

so for this input : ["123", "asdd", "Ave."] I got false . why ?

I must also say that the strange thing is that it works fine when I keep 2 conditions instead of 3 in  checkAdd

```
checkNumber:: String->Bool
checkNumber  xs =((length(filter isDigit xs ))== length(xs))

checkStreetName:: String->Bool
checkStreetName xs  =((length(filter isLetter1 xs ))== length(xs))

isLetter1:: Char->Bool
isLetter1 ch   =((ch>='A' && ch<='Z') || (ch>='a' && ch<='z'))


checkAdd :: [String]->Bool
checkAdd (num:xs) = (checkNumber num  &&  (all1 checkStreetName (tail xs)) &&        isAbbreviation (last1 xs))


all1 :: (String->Bool)->[String] -> Bool
all1 f xs = ((length(filter f xs)) == length(xs))

isAbbreviation:: String->Bool
isAbbreviation str |str=="Ave." || str=="St."    =True
               |otherwise                    =False

last1 :: [a]->a
last1 (x:[])      = x
last1 (x:xs)      =last1 xs
```

Comment: Is this for learning or real world use? For real world, this approach is not going to give you good results.

Comment: The way you are representing the adress tight now is very "stringly typed" and easily breaks. For example, you need to worry about the list having 2 or 4 elements and there is no wat to add non-string items to the list. You should consider representing the address as a tuple or using a record.

Comment: yes I could add this check.. but I am just not getting why it returns false when its valid input...

Comment: Another tip: as a rule of thumb, you don't want to be calling `length` on lists because it is inneficient and will loop forever on infinite lists. Instead of coding `all1` in terms of `filter` code it in terms of `foldr` or via manual recursion.

Comment: You could easily have figured out the problem with some ghci testing.

Comment: I know.. but I am not aloud to use the ready function "all"

Comment: @Shiran: You coded your own `all1` so you might as well code it properly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is simply that `"Ave."` contains a non-letter character, namely `'.'`, but `all1` (just a re-definition of [`all`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aall)) requires it to fulfill `checkStreetName`. To fix this, for instance test `all1 checkStreetName $ init xs` instead of `all1 checkStreetName xs`.